# gcloud app engine region does not have enough resources

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I ran into this error while trying to deploy my Node.js app on Google's App Engine:

`(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2022-01-07T08:03:21.449Z334.zf.2: The region us-west3 does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Please try again later.`

It seems like the error is with the region "not having enough resources," but how is this possible? Is it really the case that `us-west3` has run out of "capacity"? Or does this error indicate something wrong with my app? I've deployed it before on Google App Engine but I am open to the possibility that something in my code could be causing errors. I don't know what this could be, but the problem has to be on my end, right?

Comment: Yes, it means that Google does not have resources available to deploy your app. Either wait and try again, choose a different instance size, or select a different region.

Comment: I've now tried deploying it three times over the course of the past 24 hours. No luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, your problem is a vendor support problem. We cannot help you. See item #4 here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Tip: Create a new project, enable billing with the same billing account and then enable App Engine in a region with large capacity such as us-central.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by John Hanley, you will have to wait and try again, but you cannot change the [region of App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations), you will have to create another project in another region if you want to.